# Help ID adult trike with passenger chariot and extra lever in the middle

Tags: identify-this-bike, tricycle

[image: frame]

Please help identify adult trike with passenger chariot and extra lever in the middle. Extra lever maybe rear brakes perhaps?

Passenger toktok/tuktuk

[image]

[image]

Comment: As for identifying the bike specifically, it doesn't really matter. 
 Have a read of  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/

Comment: Progress: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/90690/look-at-my-trike

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is no front brake, and the left hand brake connects via a pushrod to the levers on the side of the downtube, then continue down toward the bottom bracket via another pullrod.

Clearly it is related to braking - but there's no photo that shows what the rod does under the BB.  We can see a rod going back to the center of the rear axle, and seems to be connected to the strap for a band brake, which would strap around the outside of a drum attached to the rear axle.   Can't see that drum in any photo though.

At a guess, the downtube lever is a "park brake" to hold the bike stationary while passengers are loading or unloading, and it uses some kind of over-center latch to hold itself on without having to hold the hand lever down.

Comment: Yes. Spot on about the rear brake integrated into rear axle.