# Look at my trike

Tags: identify-this-bike, parts, tricycle

About 21 days ago exactly I [posted for help identifying some junk in a barn](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/90364/help-id-adult-trike-with-passenger-chariot-and-extra-lever-in-the-middle).

Today i can show you what these parts were supposed to look like.

I've figured out a bunch during the process.
The lever between the legs is rear brake.

And the two levers on the handlebars are also rear brakes. :) no front brakes needed.

The mechanism for the brakes is just a little wheel(toothless gear) integrated into the rear axle, and when the lever is activated, a piece of "fabric" tightens around the wheel slowing down the axle.

Since it seems like a rare piece, can someone help identify it in order to try and source parts?

I know i need the handlebar brake mechanism and linkage, chains (which are loooong and thin) ...

Another option i want to ask about is resto mods. I have a frame than needs a conpltete front end. How can i measure one out, source it and have something with new technology retro fitted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No idea what the trike is, but that sounds like a form of *band brake*

Comment: Moreover, I'd suspect its a foot-operated band brake.

Comment: Hi criggie. Yes. There is a place to put ur foot attached to the hand lever. Also on the handlebar there is built in old school brake levers that trigger the same band brake. Ive got a couple of them. This is fun.

Comment: "it seems like a rare piece". No, on the contrary, it seems a very typical "antique" piece. 
If you check historical photo of trikes and rishka bicycles in SE Asia you will see plenty of similar bikes.

Comment: Hmm. I googled ur keywords. Rishka returns nothing. Lol maybe u meant rickshaw. Anyway i am in santa cruz, very far away from south east asia and i have three of those bikes. Here they look rare. Funny not one example brand was mentioned. Not a year or decade was mentioned.