# Trying to figure out this brand of bicycle and also what year did they make it?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Was given this bike a while ago and I would like to know who makes it and what year it is. It’s super light weight. [image]

Comment: Bikes have far less diversity than things like cars - so it really doesn't matter who made it or when.   The vast bulk of modern bikes are made in the far East regardless of what name appears on them.     You may be interested to read https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an orange and black painted frame made from Aluminium based on the complex curve in the top tube, which was likely made by water-forming/hydroforming.

The steerer tube and headset bearings appear to be threaded, with a Quill stem suggesting an older design.

The front fork appears to have no brakes, so this bike is not compliant with most of the world's legal requirements for a bicycle.  I presume this bike to have been sold in the USA where such laws are laxs
The front and rear wheels have nutted axles rather than a quick release, again implying an older design.  This would have been totally standard in the 80s, but by the 2000's would only appear on lower entry-level bikes.

The wheel rims themselves do not show a brake track, so they never had brakes either.  I presume the rear wheel has a coaster or back-pedal brake only.

The crank arms don't show up very well, I can't tell if they are bronze, or are partially painted orange or if its just the dark lighting in your basement.  But the crank arms appear to not have a spider, so this was always a single front chainring setup.

The rear wheel hub is impossible to see, as is the cog.  But since both wheels match they're probably original.   I do see a reaction arm on the far side of the bike, confirming the existence of a back pedal/coaster brake.

There's also a vertical tab sticking up from the chainstay, suggesting that this frame came with some kind of chain guard which has been lost or never installed.

The saddle is one of those quite-wide ones with built-in springs.  These are often found on bikes that don't get a lot of riding - they're not particularly efficient and can promote more pain than a harder saddle of suitable width.
 The saddle is also quite low - suggesting this was a kid's bike rather than an adult.   Scale's hard to see but they look like 26 or 24" wheels so a 10-16 year old approximately, or perfectly suitable for a smaller adult too.

It looks eminently rideable other than the lack of two brakes - but I can't see any good way to add brakes.   The positive is that coaster brakes rarely fail, but they're also never very good at stopping.

I'd say this is a 2000~2010ish Walmart-grade bike sold in the USA, and that it has not done a great deal of mileage in its life.... yet.