# Serial number/ head badge help needed

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, schwinn

I have what I believe is a 1983/1984 Schwinn Sidewinder 10 speed. I am trying to decipher when and where it exactly was built and the year.

The serial number on the head tube reads as- DU522482 and the Headbadge shows as 1573.
I am not having any luck finding where it was built or if it is a 83 or 84. My understanding Schwinn stopped building in Chicago in 1982. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Bike looks to be completely original except for tires and tubes.

---

[image]

<sub>from https://bikehistory.org/bikes/sidewinder/?expand_article=1</sub>

Comment: Welcome to the site - I've added a stock photo of this model to your question.  A photo of your bike would be more relevant - can you please take a clear well-lit photo and add to the question with [edit] ?

Comment: Related   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/

Comment: https://waterfordbikes.com/w/culture/schwinn-catalogs/ - I've found the Sidewinder in '82 and'84 models but I'm not sure if two pictures against the actual will be good enough to deduce the exact model year.

Comment: We need Arl to post a picture of what he/she has. I ran the serial number on a hobbiest website. It came back with 1958. There were other bikes than the 80s model the poster references. Arl could be wrong, or the serial number site could be wrong. We need a picture to know for sure.